# Convert a date and a 15 minutes time block number to complete datetime

Tags: python, python-datetime

If we divide the 24 hour time range of a day into 15 minute bins or blocks, we get 96 blocks. Hence the block=1 represents `00:00:00` hrs to `00:14:00` hrs and the `block=96` represents `23:45:00` hrs to `23:59:00` hrs.

I have two inputs, a date (say, `2020-07-25`) and a fifteen minute block number that can be any number between 1 to 96 (say, 2 i.e. `00:15:00 to 00:30:00`), from these I want to produce a complete datetime like `2020-07-25 00:15:00`

How to do this efficiently?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: with datetime module you can add `(N-1) * 15minutes` to a datetime object initialized with the value `00:00:00`and  with `N your number between 1 and 96`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, you just add an amount of minutes to a specific date based on the block number.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def operation(date, block):
    return date + timedelta(minutes=15 * (block - 1))

date = datetime.strptime("2020-07-25", "%Y-%m-%d")
block = 2
print(operation(date, block))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add both the inputs with a space like `output=input1+' ' + input2` and then convert it into datetime

```
import datetime
value=datetime.datetime.strptime(output,format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: input2 is just a block number, so first we have to resolve the time for the block number then we can do concatenation

Answer (score 0):

Generate all times in `l`, define dictionary `d` which maps `block_number` to times,
take the 2 inputs and from them construct the final datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime

l = [str(h).zfill(2) + ':' + str(m).zfill(2) + ':' + '00'
     for h in range(24)
     for m in (0, 15, 30, 45)
     ]

d = {block_number: t for block_number, t in enumerate(l)}

date_str = "2020-07-25"
block_number = 5

dt = date_str + ' ' + d.get(block_number)
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(date_time_obj)
```

Producing:

```
2020-07-25 01:15:00
```